# Join or Union Two Queries With Multiple Aggergate SUMs

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm having some difficulty combing through all the related answers here on SO. I can't seem to apply the accepted answers to my own situation without modifying the global group_all settings in my MySQL config.

I have two queries that I would like to join into a single result set or view.
The first query pulls the data from a revenue table (each row is the revenue for a day for an account with an associated week number) and the second from the spend table (with the same structure, a row for each day showing the account name, spend and associated week number).

Sample revenue table:

| account_name | week | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| acc1 | 1 | 100 |
| acc1 | 1 | 120 |
| acc1 | 1 | 150 |
| acc1 | 1 | 290 |
| acc1 | 1 | 120 |
| acc1 | 1 | 90 |
| acc1 | 1 | 100 |
| acc1 | 2 | 120 |
| acc1 | 2 | 150 |
| acc1 | 2 | 290 |
| acc1 | 2 | 120 |
| acc1 | 2 | 90 |
| acc1 | 2 | 100 |
| acc1 | 2 | 120 |
| acc2 | 1 | 150 |
| acc2 | 1 | 290 |
| acc2 | 1 | 120 |
| acc2 | 1 | 90 |
| acc2 | 1 | 100 |
| acc2 | 1 | 120 |
| acc2 | 1 | 150 |
| acc2 | 2 | 290 |
| acc2 | 2 | 120 |

The other table is the same format, just spend instead of revenue for the third column.

I'm trying to get the revenue and spend pivoted on the sum of the week for each account_name. So I'll have a weekly view of the spend and revenue in the same result set.

Each query works individually, but I'd like to have them in a single view, joined on the account_name.

Here are the queries:

```
SELECT account_name,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 1, spend, 0))) AS W1_spend,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 2, spend, 0))) AS W2_spend,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 3, spend, 0))) AS W3_spend,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 4, spend, 0))) AS W4_spend,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 5, spend, 0))) AS W5_spend,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 6, spend, 0))) AS W6_spend,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 7, spend, 0))) AS W7_spend,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 8, spend, 0))) AS W8_spend,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 9, spend, 0))) AS W8_spend,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 10, spend, 0))) AS W10_spend,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 11, spend, 0))) AS W11_spend,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 12, spend, 0))) AS W12_spend,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 13, spend, 0))) AS W13_spend,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 14, spend, 0))) AS W14_spend

FROM Q4_accountsReport
GROUP BY account_name;
```

and

```
SELECT account_name,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 1, revenue, 0))) AS W1_revenue,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 2, revenue, 0))) AS W2_revenue,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 3, revenue, 0))) AS W3_revenue,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 4, revenue, 0))) AS W4_revenue,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 5, revenue, 0))) AS W5_revenue,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 6, revenue, 0))) AS W6_revenue,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 7, revenue, 0))) AS W7_revenue,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 8, revenue, 0))) AS W8_revenue,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 9, revenue, 0))) AS W8_revenue,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 10, revenue, 0))) AS W10_revenue,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 11, revenue, 0))) AS W11_revenue,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 12, revenue, 0))) AS W12_revenue,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 13, revenue, 0))) AS W13_revenue,
   ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 14, revenue, 0))) AS W14_revenue
FROM Q4_analyticsReport
GROUP BY account_name;
```

I'd like to see w1_revenue and week1_spend by account name in the same view/result set. When I try to union or join them, I get the error that that the aggregate can't be grouped.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to merge both of these? I'd rather not have to create a new table if possible. If I'm going about the summing wrong, I'd love to know if there's a better way given the structure of the tables I have to work with.

Any advice very much appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure.... you want 15 columns as a result. Or 53 if you run that query over one year period?

Comment: There's a separate table for each quarter. So there will always only be 29 columns. 14 revenue, 14 spend and 1 account name.

Comment: Oh, that is very unusual data structure design. Usually pivoting is easiest and the most efective do in application, not in database. Excel does it easily and your queries gets much more simple and more general.

Comment: Yea, I know. I was doing this application side in Pandas which is fine. But I needed something that multiple people could access in real time. I got two working answers now so I'm delighted.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberry I'll include a full data sample next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two left join on subquery

```
    select t1.account_name , t2.W1_spend, ...., t2.W14_spend, t3.W1_revenue, ...., t2.W14_revenue, 
    from (
        select account_name 
        from  Q4_accountsReport
        UNION 
        select account_name 
        from  Q4_analyticsReport

    ) t1 
    left join (

        SELECT account_name,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 1, spend, 0))) AS W1_spend,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 2, spend, 0))) AS W2_spend,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 3, spend, 0))) AS W3_spend,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 4, spend, 0))) AS W4_spend,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 5, spend, 0))) AS W5_spend,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 6, spend, 0))) AS W6_spend,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 7, spend, 0))) AS W7_spend,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 8, spend, 0))) AS W8_spend,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 9, spend, 0))) AS W8_spend,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 10, spend, 0))) AS W10_spend,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 11, spend, 0))) AS W11_spend,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 12, spend, 0))) AS W12_spend,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 13, spend, 0))) AS W13_spend,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 14, spend, 0))) AS W14_spend

    FROM Q4_accountsReport
    GROUP BY account_name

    ) t2 ON t1.account_name = t2.account_name 

    left join (
    SELECT account_name,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 1, revenue, 0))) AS W1_revenue,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 2, revenue, 0))) AS W2_revenue,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 3, revenue, 0))) AS W3_revenue,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 4, revenue, 0))) AS W4_revenue,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 5, revenue, 0))) AS W5_revenue,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 6, revenue, 0))) AS W6_revenue,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 7, revenue, 0))) AS W7_revenue,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 8, revenue, 0))) AS W8_revenue,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 9, revenue, 0))) AS W8_revenue,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 10, revenue, 0))) AS W10_revenue,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 11, revenue, 0))) AS W11_revenue,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 12, revenue, 0))) AS W12_revenue,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 13, revenue, 0))) AS W13_revenue,
       ROUND(SUM(IF(week = 14, revenue, 0))) AS W14_revenue
    FROM Q4_analyticsReport
    GROUP BY account_name

    ) t3 ON t1.account_name = t3.account_name
```

chane the ...  with the missing cols

Comment: That worked for me too. A third/temporary table with a union seems to be what I was missing (obviously a large part!). I understand this a bit better. Thank you so much.

Comment: thanks but seems to me thatb the unique answer with the union that solve the problem related  to not simmetric accont_name  in subquey  iis the mine

Comment: Not sure I understand, are you looking for me to change the accepted answer to yours?

Comment: you can do what you prefer  adn choose the answer  you prefer ..  the first, the last, the most beatiful or the most relevant  .the most clear ..and so on .  ..  but if is important the aspect related to the accont_name list  .. then the unique asnwer  with also  this suggestion . is mine ..

Comment: As I work more on this and add additional columns from a third table, you're right @scaisEdge this is the most useful and easiest to understand answer.

Answer (score 1):

We could use the queries as inline views in an outer query. (Is there a possibility an account_name will be returned by one of the queries and not the other, and vice versa? And what do we want to do if one is missing?)

Something like this:

```
SELECT r.account_name 
     , r.W1_revenue 
     , s.W1_spend 
     , r.W2_revenue 
     , s.W2_spend 
     , ...
  FROM ( -- original revenue query here as inline view (derived table)
        SELECT qr.account_name 
             , ROUND(SUM(IF(qr.week = 1, qr.revenue, 0))) AS W1_revenue
             , ROUND(SUM(IF(qr.week = 2, qr.revenue, 0))) AS W2_revenue
             , ... 
          FROM Q4_analyticsReport qr
        GROUP BY qr.account_name
      ) r
 LEFT
 JOIN ( -- original spend query here as inline view (derived table)
        SELECT qs.account_name,
             , ROUND(SUM(IF(qs.week = 1, qs.spend, 0))) AS W1_spend
             , ROUND(SUM(IF(qs.week = 2, qs.spend, 0))) AS W2_spend
             , ...
          FROM Q4_accountsReport qs
         GROUP BY qs.account_name
      ) s
   ON s.account_name = r.account_name 
ORDER BY r.account_name
```

Comment: There will always be matching account names in both.

That worked for me. I had no idea it was possible to do an in line view like this. Thank you so much!

Comment: if both queries are guaranteed to return the same set of `account_name`, we can be done. but if this is the more usual case, and some account_name might be missing from `r`  or `s`, then we could introduce a third set, another row source that returns the entire set of account_name, call it `q`, and then we can outer join `r` and `s` i.e. `SELECT q.account_name, ... FROM ( SELECT account_name ...) q LEFT JOIN ( ... ) r ON ... LEFT JOIN ( ... ) s ON ... ORDER BY q.account_name`.  Typically, we'd have a dimension table of all distinct/unique values of account_name

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the same accounts in both tables, you can do:

```
create view v as
    with q1 as (
          firstqueryhere
         ),
         q2 as (
          secondqueryhere
         )
    select *
    from q1 join
         q2
         using (account_name);
```

Comment: I still face the same problem with this:
[2021-02-15 16:24:54] [42000][1140] In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'fy21.Q4_accountsReport.account_name'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by